# Terraform: using the file interpolation to read local file from a module

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to tell terraform that when I do something like

```
locals {
  file_content = "${file("somefile.txt")}"
}
```

Inside a module, it sould **read the file that's in the module?**

It appears that if the file structure is this:

```
/module
  /main.tf        <- the code above is here
  /somefile.txt
/project
  /main.tf        <- this uses the module from ../module
```

Terraform will look for the file under `/project` and not under `/module`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`path.module`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#path-module) to refer to the path of the module.

So in your module you would refer to it with:

```
locals {
  file_content = "${file("${path.module}/somefile.txt")}"
}
```

This is also shown in the [documentation for the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html):

```
> file("${path.module}/hello.txt")
Hello World
```